# Update the xml using python3 at specific subelement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am trying to update below xml file in python 3 using import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET but not able to add anything between  tags

Issue I am facing not able to get/fetch the tag after fileSets.
Can someone let me know how we could update the xml?

abc.xml

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2-xsd"
>
 <id></id>
 <formats>
  <format>zip</format>
 </formats>
 <fileSets>
   <fileSet>
     <outputDirectory>/<outputDirectory>
     <directory>../</directory>
       <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
       <includes>
       </includes>
   </fileSet>
 </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Expected output:(file names will be added dynamically)
abc.xml

```
<assembly
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2-xsd"
>
 <id></id>
 <formats>
  <format>zip</format>
 </formats>
 <fileSets>
   <fileSet>
     <outputDirectory>/<outputDirectory>
     <directory>../</directory>
       <useDefaultExcludes>false</useDefaultExcludes>
       <includes>
       <include>abc.text</include>
       <include>def.text</include>
       <include>ghi.text</include>
       </includes>
   </fileSet>
 </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I am trying this and it prints me all four element inside this files but doesn't know how to access includes and then add something inside this abc.txt and so on.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(abc.xml)
root = tree.getroot()
for actor in root.findall('{http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2}fileSets'):
    for name in actor.findall('{http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2}fileSet'):
        print(name)
```

Comment: So you want to add three `include` elements as children of `includes`?

Comment: @mzjn yes You can see in the expected output

Comment: abc.xml has a default namespace that you need to take into account. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: @mzjn updated the code but still doesn't know how to reach specific element and add(mentioned above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything with `fileSets` or`fileSet`. Since you want to add children to `includes`, get that element directly.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
# Ensure that the proper prefix is used in the output (in this case, no prefix at all)
ET.register_namespace("", "http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2")
 
tree = ET.parse("abc.xml")
 
# Find the 'includes' element (.// means search the whole document).
# {*} is a wildcard and matches any namespace (Python 3.8)
includes = tree.find(".//{*}includes")
 
# Create three new 'include' elements
include1 = ET.Element("include")
include1.text = "abc.text"
 
include2 = ET.Element("include")
include2.text = "def.text"
 
include3 = ET.Element("include")
include3.text = "ghi.text"
 
# Add the new elements as children of 'includes'
includes.append(include1)
includes.append(include2)
includes.append(include3)
```